# Export Excel Zend Framework

Tags: php, jquery, html, excel, zend-framework

i have a problem with exporting an excel file from php

```
    $filename = realpath($filename);
    $handle = fopen($filename, "w");

    $cols = array();

    fputcsv($handle,$cols, "\t");

    $table = array($_POST);

    foreach ($table as $row){
        fputcsv($handle, $row, "\t" );
    }

    fclose($handle);

    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    $this->getResponse()->setRawHeader( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8" )
        ->setRawHeader( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=excel.xls" )
        ->setRawHeader( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" )
        ->setRawHeader( "Expires: 0" )
        ->setRawHeader( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" )
        ->setRawHeader( "Pragma: public" )
        ->setRawHeader( "Content-Length: " . filesize($filename))
        ->sendResponse();
```

With this code I get an excel file, but the data are all in the column A(excel)
How can I get a right format? The variable $table looks like:

//EDIT
var_dump($_POST) looks like

```
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>
<tr><td>Mike</td><td>Dirnt</td></tr>
```

Comment: you need PHPExcel, just integrate it to zf2

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are actually creating a CSV file, not an XLS file. They are very different things. Save it as .csv with the content-type set to text/csv instead:

```
$this->getResponse()->setRawHeader( "Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8" )
    ->setRawHeader( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=excel.csv" )
    ->setRawHeader(.......
```

It will still open in Excel!

Comment: Sorry, the situation doesn't change :(

Comment: Then you are going to need to provide some example data. Can you do `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: If that's the output of your var_dump then something is very wrong. You need to extract the values from the table cells first. You'd better make another question about that if you're unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow up below code with your data it will work on zend. 
Also please replace with your controller class.

```
Class ExportExcelController extends Zend_Controller_Action{

public function exportexcelAction()
{
set_time_limit( 0 );

$model = new Default_Model_SomeModel();
$data = $model->getData();

$filename = APPLICATION_PATH . "/tmp/excel-" . date( "m-d-Y" ) . ".xls";

$realPath = realpath( $filename );

if ( false === $realPath )
{
touch( $filename );
chmod( $filename, 0777 );
}

$filename = realpath( $filename );
$handle = fopen( $filename, "w" );
$finalData = array();
foreach ( $data AS $row )
{
$finalData[] = array(
utf8_decode( $row["col1"] ), // For chars with accents.
utf8_decode( $row["col2"] ),
utf8_decode( $row["col3"] )
);
}

foreach ( $finalData AS $finalRow )
{
fputcsv( $handle, $finalRow, "\t" );
}

fclose( $handle );

$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

$this->getResponse()->setRawHeader( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8" )
->setRawHeader( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=excel.xls" )
->setRawHeader( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" )
->setRawHeader( "Expires: 0" )
->setRawHeader( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" )
->setRawHeader( "Pragma: public" )
->setRawHeader( "Content-Length: " . filesize( $filename ) )
->sendResponse();

readfile( $filename ); unlink($filename); exit();
}

}
```